# How to convert common format sql to mybatis support sql

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, mybatis

Here I need to convert common format sql such as:

`select * from table where id = 'abc' limit 1`

to mybatis supporting format such as:

`select * from table where id = #{id} limit #{count}`

so that sql could be executed in mybatis to aviod sql injection attack and complete different DB type convert using mybatis.

The reason why I have to use mybatis do that is because following request:
1 the orignal sql is come from user input, so have to insure the safe of that sql
2 mybatis support different DB, so no need to write code to convert field for different DB type
3 and also mybatis interception function should involved.

I have tried using Druid WallVisitorutils.check() to verify the safty of orignal sql, but I don't think that is a good way to fulfill the 3 requests.

I am considering MyBatis Dynamic SQL, but can't find a good way.

is there any suggestion?

Comment: Did you tried it with a Notepad? I meen this is not a simple `find` - `replace` you must provide the variable names... e.g for the case `trunc(start_d) = DATE'2020-01-01'`

Comment: I hava found the way to get that, mix the Druid parameter export method and mybatis dynamic sql API "Provider class".